How to replace nonbreakable spaces with regular spaces on input?
I'm having issues with text copied from e-books when pasted into source code with Vim, the "nonbreakable space" ends up with an error message from gcc at compile time.
Typical error message is:
filename.c:69:6: error: stray ‘\302’ in program
 69 | <U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0><U+00A0>return 1;

The simple solution I've used is to run :%s/\%ua0/ /g - making them regular spaces.
Is there a way to make this happen automatically on input in Vim (pasting from the terminal that is), for example a command or setting in .vimrc?

Simple: don't copy and paste source code.

Brilliant, how do I mark this as solved ?

Don't bother. Deleting the question will do.

Could we give the sarcasm a break and focus on the question?

What sarcasm? OP would be better off if they focused on the root cause of their problem, over-reliance on copypasta in this case, instead of wasting everyone's time asking for workarounds to their bad practices.

@romainl I'm sure you could write a great answer that explains this in a way OP would understand it. I'd even argue that - for somebody trying to learn a language - playing with code from books may be instructive.

@romainl I think the old saying, "One man's stupid question is another man's quest for enlightenment" is relevant.

The idea behind copy and paste is that you insert the copied content verbatim.
Once you decide to change it on the fly, you call for surprises.
Your idea of pasting first and removing non-breaking spaces in a second pass already seems like a sensible idea.
You can speed the process up with a key binding as described in Ciaran's answer.
Having said that, you can use an autocommand to remove non-breaking spaces before saving your buffer to a file.
It has the caveat that this will remove all non-breaking spaces, not just the ones you pasted.
It will cause unwanted behavior e.g. when your source code contains Unicode strings containing non-breaking spaces.
To enable this only for C files, add a buffer-local autocommand to your ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim like this:
augroup remove_non_breaking_spaces
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> %s/\%uA0/ /ge
augroup END

See :help :autocmd for general reference and :help BufWritePre for the specific event.
Also see :help :augroup for an explanation of the augroup guard.
(An earlier version of my answer triggered on the InsertLeave event but it's really enough to do this before writing the file.)
To generalize your solution to other non-ASCII characters, also see How to get Vim to highlight non-ascii characters?

I don't know if there is a way to do what you want automatically. However, the way I would approach it would be to use the vim map command to map a particular key sequence to a command to be executed. In effect, this sets up a new command that you can type outside of text insertion mode.
To illustrate the concept, here are two mappings I have in my .vimrc file (I'm using ^M to denote an embedded newline character. You can embed this by typing <Control>+v followed by <Enter>.
map MM :!clear^M:!make^M
map FF /\${[^}]*}^M

The first mapping, MM, causes two shell commands to be run. The first command is clear, and the second command is make.
The second mapping, FF, performs a search to highlight text of the form ${<something>} (I use this to highlight placeholder variables in a template file).
Based on the above examples, I think the following will do what you want (choose whatever key sequence you want; I'm just using UU as an example):
map UU :%s/\%ua0/ /g^M

If you use the above mapping, then whenever you type UU (outside of text insert mode), the global search-and-replace will be performed.

Some remarks to help you improve your mappings: 1) you should use :nnoremap by default unless you explicitly need anything else (read :help :map-overview for the differences); and 2) prefer Vim's :make command; finally 3) you can use <CR> which is more readable and (arguably) easier to type than ^M.

@Friedrich, thanks for those useful tips.
